# Tests down if run with Robolectric for apps with data-binding in module(s)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

Tests couldn't go on if the App is based on multi-modules.

A normal app
 - base-app(baseFeature)
 - some other modules
 - install (apk)
 - instant (instant app)

I have added all these in `gradle.properties`, however, the tests cannot go on, they throw 

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/databinding/DataBinderMapperImpl`

`android.enableD8.desugaring=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true`

I am sure that all works before I switched to multi-modules.

Version of robolectric: 3.7.1

[issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3789)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @dazza5000 nothing progress

Comment: facing the same issue in robolectric 4.2 and androidX